# How to change visualstate from code behind?

Tags: visualstatemanager

How to change visualstate from code behind?
I tried the following. But itz not working. Help me please.

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(Control, "Checked", true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(Control, "Checked", true);
```